# how to send iterated json data to html Id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My html and json with jquery is below. please someone help me to do this in javascript function.
Is there any other way without using clone function?
with pure javascript can we do this any other way to display json content in HTML id's

```js
$(function () {
    // Fake JSON result - array of values
    json = [{
        fields: {
            imagem: "Image 1",
            nome_produto: "Name 1",
            descricao: "Description 1",
            preco_produto: "product 1"
        }
    }, {
        fields: {
            imagem: "Image 2",
            nome_produto: "Name 2",
            descricao: "Description 2",
            preco_produto: "product 2"
        }
    }, {
        fields: {
            imagem: "Image 3",
            nome_produto: "Name 3",
            descricao: "Description 3",
            preco_produto: "product 3"
        }
    }];
    
    // take a copy of an existing one as a template
    $.each(json, function (i, items) {
        var clone = $('.conteudo:first').clone();
        clone.find('.foto').text(items.fields['imagem']);
        clone.find('.inf:eq(0)').text(items.fields['nome_produto']);
        clone.find('.inf:eq(1)').text(items.fields['descricao']);
        clone.find('.inf:eq(2)').text(items.fields['preco_produto']);
        $('section').append(clone);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="foto">FOTO</div>
        <div class="inf">TITULO</div>
        <div class="inf">DESCRICAO</div>
        <div class="inf">PRECO</div>
    </div>
    
</section>
```

My html and json with jquery is below. please someone help me to do this in javascript function.
Is there any other way without using clone function?
with pure javascript can we do this any other way to display json content in HTML id's
result should be json data like below

```
        Image 1
        Name 1
        Description 1
        product 1

        Image 2
        Name 2
        Description 2
        product 2
        Image 3
        Name 3
        Description 3
        product
```

Comment: Cloning a template is a good way to do this. You can also use `document.createElement` to build the structure from scratch in JS.

Comment: its just a example I have big project . I am not able to clone for graph data. could you please send me fiddle link how to do same stuff in javascript

Comment: @Tavish Aggarwal  can you get expected out with diffrent javascript function without cloning

Comment: Why don't you want to clone?

Comment: You can store the html of conteudo in a variable and when iterating your json, you can set values in it. After iteration completion, you can append the whole html to the section

Comment: What do you mean _"display json content in HTML id's"_ You wouldnt put content in the ids. Or do you mean you want to put the content into elements of which you have an id? ie, you have an element like `<div id="here"></div>` and you have the id `here` but dont know how to get the element in order to put the content into it?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes i want to put the contents into elements which have id

Comment: @RajeshChoudary see my answer below

Comment: @madalinivascu see my requires result above. I should get only json data. not the data iside div elements

Comment: you want to append the json on the page?

Comment: @madalinivascu  yes to the specific ids

Comment: there isn't any property in your json named "id", you mean the number at the end of your strings?

Comment: @madalinivascu I mean class foto should get json.fields.imagem    and class inf should get json.feilds.nome_produto... likewise it should loop

Comment: you want to append to the class attribute the values from the json ?

Comment: @madalinivascu yes from json to html class.

Comment: you mean something like `<div class="foto Image 1">FOTO</div>` ?yes?

Comment: @madalinivascu no its like <div class="foto ">Image 1</div> and  in next loop <div class="foto ">Image 2</div>. you got the result but it should not  display this  <div class="foto">FOTO</div>

Comment: lol man,that is easy ,see my updated snippet

Comment: you just remove the html from the page because we are building our html we don't need them anymore

Comment: @madalinivascu no in your updates snippet first four results are from html div elements. my problem is its should not display that first four results FOTO
TITULO
DESCRICAO
PRECO

Comment: @madalinivascu I know to remove those div elemts as well. is there any other way without removing div elements

Comment: @RajeshChoudary you want them removed or you don't want them removed?

Comment: @RajeshChoudary you can hide them using `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

You can build the html as a string using concatenation: 
To add a unique id to each row use the index `i` variable provided by the foreach loop

```js
$(function () {
    // Fake JSON result - array of values
    json = [{
        fields: {
            imagem: "Image 1",
            nome_produto: "Name 1",
            descricao: "Description 1",
            preco_produto: "product 1"
        }
    }, {
        fields: {
            imagem: "Image 2",
            nome_produto: "Name 2",
            descricao: "Description 2",
            preco_produto: "product 2"
        }
    }, {
        fields: {
            imagem: "Image 3",
            nome_produto: "Name 3",
            descricao: "Description 3",
            preco_produto: "product 3"
        }
    }];
    
    // take a copy of an existing one as a template
    $.each(json, function (i, items) {
        var clone = '<div class="conteudo" id="conteudo'+i+'"><div class="foto">'+items.fields['imagem']+'</div><div class="inf">'+items.fields['nome_produto']+'</div><div class="inf">'+items.fields['descricao']+'</div><div class="inf">'+items.fields['preco_produto']+'</div></div>'
       
        $('section').append(clone);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
   
    
</section>
```

Comment: do you know how to stop getting first four result which are coming from dic elements

Comment: what dic elements?